# How to show the eigenvectors is preserved under a ODE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Assume $V$ is a 3-dimsional vector space. And
$$
\varphi(t):V\rightarrow V
$$
is nondegenerate  linear map, and  smooth respect to $t$. The eigenvalues  of $\varphi(t)$ are
$$
\lambda_1(t)\le \lambda_2(t)\le\lambda_3(t)
$$
the eigenvectors are $e_1(t), ...,e_3(t)$. Respect to  the basis $e_1(t), ...,e_3(t)$ (we always assume $e_1(t), ...,e_3(t)$ can be the basis of $V$, in fact, I feel the nondegenerate of $\varphi(t)$  can guarantee it), $\varphi(t)$ satisfy
$$
\frac{d\varphi(t)}{dt} = 2
\left(\begin{array}{1}
 \lambda_1^2(t) +\lambda_2(t)\lambda_3(t)   &0   &0\\
 0   &\lambda_2^2(t) +\lambda_1(t)\lambda_3(t)   &0   \\
 0   &0   &\lambda_3^2(t) +\lambda_1(t)\lambda_2(t)
\end{array}
\right)
\tag{1}
$$
Then, how to show $e_i(t) =e_i(0)$ for $i=1,.,3$  ? Namely,
$$
\varphi(t)(e_i(0)) = \lambda_i(t)e_i(0)
$$

**PS**: I want to explain how to understand (1). First, $\varphi(t)$ is linear map satisfy
$$
\frac{d\varphi(t)}{dt} = 2\Gamma
$$
where $\Gamma=\Gamma(t)$ also be linear map. When we choose suitable basis of $V$, the linear map $\Gamma$ can be presented as matrix. For example, choose the unit eigenvectors of $\lambda_1(t)...\lambda_3(t)$ as basis of $V$, then,  the matrix of $\Gamma$ is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{1}
 \lambda_1^2(t) +\lambda_2(t)\lambda_3(t)   &0   &0\\
 0   &\lambda_2^2(t) +\lambda_1(t)\lambda_3(t)   &0   \\
 0   &0   &\lambda_3^2(t) +\lambda_1(t)\lambda_2(t)
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Now, we have $(1)$.

Comment: What is the ODE here? $\dot v(t)=\phi(t)v(t)$? Where does the equation for $\dot \phi$ come from? Is there a larger framework around this question?

Comment: @LutzLehmann  It is not $\dot v(t)=\phi(t)v(t)$. I have edit the problem, and explain how to understand the ODE. Thanks your advise.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to identify a linear map with its matrix representation in a specific basis. But you want to express that the coefficients of the derivative in the eigenbasis get that specific form? Note that in general with a special basis (the eigenbasis) that depends on location you get connection coefficients for parallel transport, curvature etc.

Comment: @LutzLehmann  Sorry for my bad English. I don't know if I understand what you mean. Seemly, you means the way will bring some troublesome. But it is a step of curvature pinching estimation in Ricci flow. I feel  it is artful and skilled.